# Using the methods of conditional proofs - logic

Tags: logic

[image]

use method of conditional proof to show the statement is a tautology.
check my solution please

Comment: Except for the images, this is an exact duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652863/use-the-methods-of-conditional-proof). The same comment as there applies: **Type it in, please. And remember to explain which part of it you have doubts about.**

Comment: i changed my solution. Plz plz check if my proof is true or not.

Comment: You still neither typed it in, nor explained which part of it you are unsure about.

Comment: I can not type it in. I hope you can read it. i want you to check if my proof is logically OKAY.

Comment: Incidentally, the question linked no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think the section about discharging should be debugged a bit. For one thing, it's not clear to me what job proof-theoretic terms such as discharging or conitional proof is supposed to do in a semantic context such as showing that some formula is a tautology. I suppose that what you mean is applying the (semantic version of the) deduction theorem for propositional logic:

For any set of formulas $\Sigma$ and any formulas $\phi, \psi$: $\Sigma \cup \lbrace \phi \rbrace \models \psi$ if and only if $~\Sigma \models \phi \rightarrow \psi$

($\models$ stands for semantic consequence.) In the discharging section you misapplied the deduction theorem at some point. So, let's reason it through a bit. You correctly showed that $\lbrace p \rightarrow q, p\rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)\rbrace \cup \lbrace p \rbrace \models r$. A first application of the theorem thus yields $\lbrace p \rightarrow q \rbrace \cup \lbrace p\rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)\rbrace \models p \rightarrow r$ (this may be read into the first line of the discharging section).

A second application of the theorem yields $\emptyset \cup \lbrace p \rightarrow q \rbrace \models (p\rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$ (so, the formula in the second line of your section should be the antecedent of a conditional having $p \rightarrow r$ as consequent).

A final application results in $\emptyset \models p \rightarrow q  \rightarrow [(p\rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)]$ (this may be read into the third line). Since consequences from the empty set are tautologies this finishes the demonstration.

Comment: You can also use the *soundness* of propositional logic; this $(P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)) \rightarrow((P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow R))$ is *(A2)* of Mendelson (4th ed, 1997), or see [Hilbert system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system). You can prove the formula of the OP using assumptions and *Deduction theorem*, then invoking *soundness* to prove that it is a *tautology*.

Comment: True, there are many paths to truth. But the one you suggested is quite arduous (at least for me), since it presupposes the syntactic version of the deduction theorem, which is awkward to prove in an axiomatic setting.